# Simple Javascript is not working exactly what I want

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate the array, however, after printing out all values in the array, it prints an undefined, I wondered why this is happening and how I can fix it. Thanks!

```
var utilities = {
    printAllMembers:function(targetObject){
        for(i in targetObject){
            document.write("<br>"+targetObject[i]);
        }
    }
}
var batman=[];
    batman[0]="batman";
    batman[1]="batman@bat.man";
    batman[2]="male";

document.write(utilities.printAllMembers(batman));
```

Answer (score 3):

> it prints an undefined, I wondered why this is happening...

Because you've told it to here:

```
   document.write(utilities.printAllMembers(batman));
// ^
```

That will call `utilities.printAllMembers`, and then it will output the result of calling the function. Since the function doesn't return a value, the result of calling it is `undefined`.

> ...and how I can fix it

To just call it, just call it:

```
utilities.printAllMembers(batman);
```

---

Side note: Don't use `for-in` (without safeguards) to loop through array indexes, that's not what it's for. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) has a full discussion and the various options you have for looping through arrays.

---

Side note 2: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you never declare `i`. Remember to declare your variables, with `var` (through ES5) or `let` (ES6+, not yet well-supported in the wild as of August 2015).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using `document.write()` twice - in the `printAllMembers()` function *and* when you call that function.  As mentioned above the `for-in` loop is malformed and misused - instead use a regular `for-loop` or a `while-loop` as below.

```
var utilities = {
    printAllMembers:function(targetObject){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < targetObject.length){
            document.write("<br>"+targetObject[i]);
            i += 1;
        }
    }
};
var batman=[];
    batman[0]="batman";
    batman[1]="batman@bat.man";
    batman[2]="male";

utilities.printAllMembers(batman);
```

See [This Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) for more info on Loops and Iteration.